# Is there a way to generate more than 50 promotion codes for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Question says it all ... is there a way to generate more than 50 promotion codes for an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I've found, but you get a fresh 50 when you release a new version of the app